# React and Redux architecture review

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-router-flux

I´m new to react world and I´m trying to understaand what´s the best way to architecture my code.

Actually, it´s a react-native using react-native-router-flux, but I don´t believe these make any difference to the question.

I´ve tried to setup a splash screen like this:

```
/* @flow */
'use strict';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';

import { init } from "../core/auth/actions"

import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.authState.authenticated,
        showLock: state.authState.showLock
    }
}

class Splash extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const {dispatch} = this.props;
        dispatch(init());
    }

    navigateToHome(){
        Actions.home();
    }

    navigateToLogin(){
        Actions.login();
    }

    render() {

        const { isAuthenticated, showLock } = this.props

        return (
            <View>
                {isAuthenticated &&
                    this.navigateToHome()
                }
                {showLock && this.navigateToLogin()}
            </View>

        );
    }

}

const connectedSplash = connect(mapStateToProps)(Splash)

export default connectedSplash;
```

When the application starts, this scene gets rendered, and a init action is dispatched.
After passing through a reducer it changes the state to either authenticated or showlock, and then I´m redirecting to the next scene.

It all works perfectly actually. However I´m getting the following warning:

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state
>   transition (such as within `render` or another component's
>   constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and
>   state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved
>   to `componentWillMount`.

What would be the recommended way to accomplish something similar?

I.e upon a store state change call a method?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the best possible way, but this approach seemed already better to me:

```
    componentDidUpdate(){
    const { isAuthenticated, showLock } = this.props
    if (isAuthenticated){
        return this.navigateToHome();
    }

    if (showLock){
        this.navigateToLogin();
    }

}

render() {


    return (
        <View>

        </View>

    );
}
```